# What is the best way to load data from SOAP APIs in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

Have to load data from soap wsdl and store in Azure Blob storage. How can we do in Azure Data Factory

Comment: add an azure functions or Azure Logic Apps activity that will invoke the SOAP WS

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Can it be done using Python in Azure Functions ? And Logic Apps has SOAP pass through in preview mode

Comment: you can write the functions on which programming language you want.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is based on HTTP protocol. so you can use HTTP as the source dataset in Azure Datafactory Copy Activity to acheive what you want.

Please check this document for specific steps:

https://medium.com/@gabrielsribe/consuming-a-soap-service-using-azure-data-factory-copy-data-activity-a4a3332cc4c

Comment: Yes. Thanks but the data that is generated by this approach is in binary format (even though it is XML). Also files don't have .xml extension with this approach. I want to convert this into JSON for further processing by ADF.